# Enable Xdebug on Apache 2 Debian 11

Tags: apache2, xdebug, php-7.4

I need to debug an PHP application running on a Apache 2 web-server.
But Xdebug doesn't seam to do anything at all; the config is loaded correctly as I can seen in my `phpinfo()`.

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[debug]
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
#xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/tmp"
#xdebug.client_host = ip-of-my-desktop
#xdebug.log = "/tmp/xdebug.log"
#xdebug.default_enable = 1
#xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
xdebug.log_level = 10
xdebug.log =  "debug"
xdebug.output_dir = /tmp
```

I tried many combinations but nothing worked.

- No profile file are generated an no one tried to connect to my machine on port 90000.
- The xdebug.log line had also no effect, no file has been created.

Thanks for your help, I am running out of ideas I managed to get it to work on Debian 9 machine.

xdebug part from phpinfo()

```
Development Aids    ✔ enabled   
Coverage    ✘ disabled  
GC Stats    ✘ disabled  
Profiler    ✘ disabled  
Step Debugger   ✘ disabled  
Tracing ✘ disabled  
Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.client_discovery_header  no value    no value
xdebug.client_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.client_port  9003    9003
xdebug.cloud_id no value    no value
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_params   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms   200 200
xdebug.coverage_enable  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.default_enable   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.discover_client_host Off Off
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level   0   0
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.log  debug   debug
xdebug.log_level    10  10
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1
xdebug.mode develop develop
xdebug.output_dir   /tmp    /tmp
xdebug.overload_var_dump    (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_connect_back  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_enable    (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_host  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_log_level (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_mode  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_port  (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.remote_timeout   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)   (setting removed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.start_upon_error default default
xdebug.start_with_request   default default
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)   (setting renamed in Xdebug 3)
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

PS: I installed the package php-xdebug
PPS: Xdebug v3.0.2

Comment: Which version of Xdebug have you loaded? The phpinfo() output will tell you.

Comment: Says Xdebug v3.0.2

Comment: Xdebug v3 uses port **9003** by default while previous Xdebug v2 was using 9000. I suggest you show the whole live output of the `xdebug_info()` (or the whole Xdebug section from `phpinfo()`) captured in the *same way* as you are trying to debug (a web page or a CLI -- it's quite common now to have different configs for them)

Comment: Done, copy pasted from phpinfo()

Comment: 1) Well, you have `Step Debugger   ✘ disabled`; The same for all other bits. No wonder that it does nothing. https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug -- make `mode` to have `debug` there: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode 2) `xdebug.log  debug   debug` -- point to a specific file (full absolute path), ideally in a folder where other logs are stored and not temp. 3) BTW (just in case) -- Xdebug will be trying to connect to `localhost:9003` and will require "debug me" flag to start (look into xdebug.start_with_request` param for auto start)

Comment: On top of what @LazyOne said: https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: I added `xdebug.log =  "debug"
xdebug.output_dir = /tmp
xdebug.trigger_value="XDEBUG_ECLIPSE"
xdebug.start_with_request = "yes"`, but still nothing happends. Step debugger is still disabled, no traffic on port 9003.
I also use the firefox plugin for debugging.

Comment: Also added "XDEBUG_SESSION=1" do my systemd config, still no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am uncertain why this is working now.

Now I have this config.

```
xdebug.mode="debug"
xdebug.trigger_value="XDEBUG_ECLIPSE"
xdebug.start_with_request="yes"
xdebug.client_host="myip"
```

Cookies and environment variables did not change anything.